# If i secure magmi will my scripts on the server still be able to access it?

Tags: security, php-5.4, magmi

I recently discovered that my magmi ui in magento is not secured. I found instructions on securing it but I need to ensure that my scripts can still access it when I secure it. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: How did you secure it - by what means? Htaccess / basic auth?

Comment: I secured it using .htaccess

Comment: order allow, deny   deny all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Htaccess security **only prevents** directory-level access to **external requests via Apache**. In that case, it is still possible to read/write to the directory from other scripts.

A good example of this from Magento is that the `var` directory has a standalone .htaccess:

```
$ cat var/.htaccess 
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

The directory can be written to from the application, but cannot be read, indexed or otherwise traversed via the web interface.